# Mathimatical plotting

Tags: performance, plot, comparison

I want to make an application that plots mathematical functions, I'd like to know the best language for it. it should have the following features:

- An area to draw the function.
- Supports anti-aliasing.
- A scroll bar to change other dependent variables (which is **a** in y=(x-a)*x).
- It should be fast enough (calculations will be done hundreds of times).
- Parsing mathematical expressions using regex (Is there a better way?).

any other suggestions would be useful.

**edit:** this can be useful in many ways such as discarding repeated calculations

ex: plotting y=4+1 using 1000 points have 999 repeated calculation, performance can be enhanced using a tree model that recalculates nodes with changed children only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex will not do for parsing math expressions.
Personally, I write recursive-descent parsers. You might be surprised how easy and flexible it is.

If you want the output to look like it's varying continuously, when it isn't actually, what I do is not paint to the output window.
Rather I paint to a memory bitmap, which I then block-transfer to the visible window.
This eliminates all flashing, and makes it look fast even if it's only actually being repainted a few times per second.

Remember, your time-hog is much more likely to be painting, not calculating, so don't waste time trying to figure out how to optimize the calculation.

As far as a "best language", it depends what you're trying to do.
I've done all this in C, C++, and C#.
I'm sure Java or other compiled languages would work just as well.

Comment: Numerical integration consumes much time. I did this in JavaScript and found that calculations take more than plotting

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a "best language" for it, however I can give you some hints. I think one way would be to use C++ with gnuplot library. Another way would be to use C++ with Qt and qwt libraries. Qt will easily manage regex too.

The latest is a solution I've personally used in my past work and there aren't particular problems, while the first is only a theoretic idea.

Comment: I want to do every thing myself ,I mean parsing the expression, getting the points, plotting, I think it would be faster because i can skip repeated calculations. **for example:** plotting y=4+1 using 1000 point have 999 repeated calculation which could be discarded.

Comment: Then you should use c++ with Qt and qwt.